# Can't load static files after cloning a Django project

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I know this question has been asked a lot but I really can't figure out why my static files won't be loaded. I cloned a project from a friend(no idea if that has anything to do with it) and when try to link to the static files I keep getting the 404 error in the debug console on Chrome.

header in my HTML

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="{% static 'css/hover.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-override.css' %}">
</head>

import os
import datetime

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DJANGO_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(DJANGO_DIR))
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = **** 

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "django.contrib.sites",

    #3rd Party APPS
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_jwt',
    'cuser', #https://github.com/tmm/django-username-email
    "pinax.stripe",

    #Custom modules
    'api',

    #Own apps
    'apps.user',
    'apps.payment',
]

# Custom user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'

# SITE_ID for the Sites framework
SITE_ID = 1

PINAX_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY", "**")
PINAX_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY", "**")


JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=14)
}

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'audit_log.middleware.UserLoggingMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(DJANGO_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(DJANGO_DIR, 'email_templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/project/static/'

MEDIA_URL = 'django/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django/')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(auth_urls)),
    url(r'^', include(user_urls)),
    url(r'^', include(referral_urls)),
    url(r'^', include(payment_urls)),
    url(r'^', include(cabinet_urls)),
    # Admin
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/feedback/', FeedbackView.as_view()),
]

if common.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(common.MEDIA_URL, document_root=common.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(common.STATIC_URL, document_root=common.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I think I've tried everything, I'm having no problem loading `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_URL`

Here's a screenshot of my project structure

[image: Pretty sure my folders are in the right place]

Comment: `if common.DEBUG:`..?? does your settings.py file has been renamed or do you have more than one settings file?

Comment: try to fire `$ python manage.py collectstatic`, This will copy all files from your static folders into the STATIC_ROOT directory.

Comment: or simply copy all static file into static folder.

Comment: I don't quite understand.. Do you have `load static` in your settings.py??

Comment: Do you want to get hacked or something? Remove the secret key! To your Problem: try this: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')`
You can add this into the settings.py as well:`print "base dir path", STATIC_ROOT` It shows you the path to your static file so you can check if its the right path. If you run this local it should be something like  ` /Users/Name/Desktop/project/static`

Comment: @FazilZaid the guy I cloned it from renamed the file

Comment: @hansTheFranz Okay so when I get it to print the base directory path is doesn't display the entire path it seems. It only displays `/project/static/` like I defined it in the `STATIC_ROOT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/project/static/')`

The static files can be tricky and there are many reasons why they won't load. You say your media files are loading properly and its because you reference them like `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django/')`. If you would Print that Path (`print MEDIA_ROOT`) something like this would come in your console: "ThisPC/Documents/Github/django/media". This path leads directly to your Media Folder but when django is looking for the Static Root it won't find the folder since you only said "project/static" but it should be "ThisPC/Documents/Github/project/static" (or similar to this).

If you ask why your friend did that, its because you only upload the GitHub folder when you go in production and there the static path would be correct. The Media files won't work like this in production.

What Fazil Zaid pointed out in the comments is also important. In your urls.py file you have `if common.DEBUG:`, usually you would use `if settings.DEBUG:` (for `Debug = True` in the settings.py file) change that line or find out what common.py is and why he used it. It seems to be an extra settings file. I would nor recommend to use it if you are not familiar with the project.

Before you push that project to production you want to change the `Secret Key` and install [White Noise](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whitenoise) for the static files. I hope that helps and will do the trick.

p.s. what exactly is this? 
`PINAX_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY", "sk_test_7dTOnMGX55bNC2yQ4ihqsHuV")
PINAX_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY", "pk_test_LutZeiAuAewyQhJuLLUJXdfi")` And you also posted the secret key of the project? You know when its just some hobby Site so you can practice its all fun and games but when payments are involved you can get sued for posting things like this online. If a Users bank account details get hacked (and that quite easy with all the passwords you are providing) you have huge Problems. PLEASE remember to change all of these before pushing anything online. Happy Coding :)

> Edit:
>   Try this one: 
>       `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), '/project/static')` or hardcoded `STATIC_ROOT = users/elitebook/documents/github/project/static/`

The Path should be correct. That is definitely your Problem or at least one of the major ones. Django does not know where to look for the static files. If it does not work copy the printed Media Path, edit it and then put the hardcoded path into your settings file. This should be the Path: `STATIC_ROOT = users/elitebook/documents/github/project/static/` Not sure if a `C:/` is infront of that part or not look at the Media root and try to copy the first part and edit the second so it points to static instead of Media. When Debug is True and your files still don't load than you have another Problem somewhere else.

Comment: I tried  `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/project/static/')` and it displays `base dir path C:/project/static/` so exactly what I put in the code. So I tried providing the full path: `users/elitebook/documents/github/project/static/` and what was printed was different oddly: ` `C:\Users\elitebook\documents\github\proswap\backend\django\core\users/elitebook/documents/github/proswap/static/` could that be a clue?`

Comment: Also `common.py` is the only setting file I see, however when I run the server the shell tells me `Django version 1.9.4, using settings 'core.settings'` in the "core" folder on my computer there's a *folder* named "settings" but not a file. So i tried renaming common.py to settings.py and placed it in the "core" folder. but still nothing

Comment: I don't know what the `PINAX` code is, I know what pinax is but not sure what that does. Im just trying to code a profile page right now and cant get these damn files to load lol

Comment: Ok in this case your Settings file is ok, you should keep the name common.py. I taught its a second file. Pinax/Stripe is a Payment Servies. The Secret Key is used to get into the API. You don't want anybody to have this password since they could get into your payment system with that (the bad way). 
For the Static Part please look into the edit answer.

Comment: @Amon I can totally understand your frustration you just want to take a look at the project but can't get the thing to load it would drive me crazy...

Comment: Thanks a lot again man, it's still not working. And interestingly when I changed the same back from `common.py` to `settings.py` it stopped printing the test line I put at the bottom. The `print base dir` line. And when I run the server it says `Django version 1.11.3, using settings 'core.settings'` but `settings` is only a folder, there's no `settings.py` file like that message implies

Comment: Also he told just told me he was using `gulp` to copy the html and css files into another folder: `/httpdocs/` I didn't know this originally. But would this matter? I should still be able to do this the conventional way no?

Comment: No idea what's going on lol, I just deleted everything in `common.py` and the server still ran. How does that make sense?

Comment: scratch that last part, was my mistake. But yea still not functioning lol

Comment: gave you the accepted answer because of your help so far

Comment: very nice that you did that but im not here for the points. Its quite strange that it is so hard to get the static files to run when debug = True because the tricky part usually starts when you put it to False. And as you said it should work in the conventional way. does the folder `/httpdocs/` has a static folder inside? When you Set the path to your normal static folder do you still get the same error message? like no static file found? You said you use the browser console. What does your terminal say?

Comment: OMG I figured it out

Comment: I ran the command `python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 css/styles.css` and it returned `Looking in the following locations:
  C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static
  C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\static`

Comment: I placed the static files in that location and now they're being loaded, I'm so relieved but I don't know why it's looking in that static folder instead of the one I specified in the settings

Comment: Nice to hear that its finally working. I don't know why I forgot about `findstatic` that should have done the trick before. Anyway I hope that you can achieve what your actual plan was with this project. Call me when you change go `Debug=False` than the party starts from beginning ;)